# If I write a custom property getter method, will KVO still operate if the getter returns a value by accessing a value from another object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, key-value-observing

Assume that I have a class with a readonly property on it.

```
//MyClass.h
@interface MyClass

@property (readonly) NSInteger MonitorMe;

@end
```

Now, let's assume the point of this property is to monitor changes of another property, within another object, and when the property is "observed" it returns a derived value by inspecting a value from the other, external object.

```
//MyClass.m
@implementation

@synthesize MonitorMe;
-(NSInteger) getMonitorMe
{
    return globalStaticClass.OtherNSInteger;
}

... Inits and Methods ...
@end
```

Now, let's assume that some where I create an instance of the `MyClass` object, and I want to add a KVO observer on the `MonitorMe` property.

```
//AnotherClass.m
@implementation AnotherClass.m

    @synthesize instanceOfMyClass;

    -(id)init
    {
        ...
        instanceOfMyMethod = [MyClass init];
            [MyClass addObserver: self 
                  forKeyPath: @"MonitorMe" 
                     options: NSKeyValuObservingOptionNew
                     context: nil];
        ...
    }
```

My question is, since the `MonitorMe` property only monitors the changes of values in an external object, will the observer method execute when the value of `globalStaticClass.OtherNSInteger` changes?  Also, if the answer is yes, **how is this done?**

If this works, it would seem like compiler voodoo to me.

**Note**

I don't think it makes a difference, but I am using ARC for this implementation and I'm compiling for an iOS device.  I doubt there are compilation differences between OS X and iOS for this type of question but, if it matters, I have an iOS project that requires such an implementation outlined above.

Also, the example outlined above is a very basic setup of my actual needs.  It could be argued that I could/should add an observation to the `globalStaticClass.OtherNSInteger` value instead of the readonly property, `MonitorMe`.  In my actual circumstance that answer is not sufficient because my readonly property is much more complex than my example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> will the observer method execute when the value of `globalStaticClass.OtherNSInteger` changes?

No, but you *can* make that happen, via `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingMonitorMe` (or the more generic `+keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`, if the "globalStaticClass" is actually a property of MyClass. See ["Registering Dependent Keys"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE) in the KVO Guide.

Here's a quick mockup:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Monitored : NSObject 
@property NSInteger otherInteger;
@end

@implementation Monitored
@synthesize otherInteger;
@end

@interface Container : NSObject 
@property (readonly) NSInteger monitorMe;
@property (strong) Monitored * theMonitored;

- (void)changeMonitoredInteger;
@end

@implementation Container

@synthesize theMonitored;

+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingMonitorMe {

    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"theMonitored.otherInteger"];
}

- (id) init {

    self = [super init];
    if( !self ) return nil;

    theMonitored = [[Monitored alloc] init];
    [theMonitored setOtherInteger:25];

    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)monitorMe
{
    return [[self theMonitored] otherInteger];
}

- (void)changeMonitoredInteger {

    [[self theMonitored] setOtherInteger:arc4random()];
}

@end

@interface Observer : NSObject 
@end

@implementation Observer

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    NSLog(@"Observing change in: %@ %@", keyPath, object);
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Observer * o = [[Observer alloc] init];
        Container * c = [[Container alloc] init];

        [c addObserver:o
            forKeyPath:@"monitorMe"
               options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
               context:NULL];

        [c changeMonitoredInteger];
        [c changeMonitoredInteger];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Cocoa style notes: properties/variables should have lowercase initial letters, and (this is actually more important now because of ARC) don't name accessor methods to start with "get" -- that has a specific meaning in Cocoa involving passing in a buffer and getting data back by reference.

Comment: I did not realize that naming methods with "get" in ARC was a problem! Yikes, I need to rewrite some code now.  Thank you!

Comment: To be completely fair, I'm not absolutely _certain_ that it will cause problems, but that is a very well-established convention in Cocoa, and I know that ARC uses method names to reason about the management of return values.

Comment: Jacques: You posted a link above that appears to be specific to OS X 10.4 and 10.5.  Is the information also relavent to iOS 5.1?

Comment: I believe so; I just tested the same code on the 5.1 simulator and it works the same. The doc on the iOS side is identical: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE

Comment: HA! So it is, complete with the references to the OS X versions.  Apple faux pas!

Comment: They do that all the time, just like I post OS X answers to iOS questions all the time. :]